# Disk encryption password prompt doesn't appear - Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux, linux-mint, disk-encryption

I've installed Linux Mint 17.1 on my desktop computer with full disk encryption set up. Upon starting my computer and after the splash screen, a black screen appears, and does not move on. If I type my encryption password and press enter, it will accept it and move on to the login screen, however there's nothing actually showing that I'm typing into.

I have the same version of Linux installed on my laptop, and am greeted with [this](https://i.imgur.com/KhvxEsq.jpg) screen instead of a completely black one.

Is there any way that I can get that prompt to appear on my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

the way it is behaving on desktop TECHNICALLY is proper but try

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k all && sudo update-grub`

(ensuring if needed --true FDE) that the `cpio` and `cryptodisk=1`  arguments are in grub.d/....  FIRST

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Linux Mint 19 with kernel:

```
4.15.0-109-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 02:39:32 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

To see the decryption prompt I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this on Linux Mint 17.3. It appears to be an upstream bug, possibly due to which kernel you are running (I also suspect it's got to do with me using UEFI, but no confirmation on that). See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1359689) for more info, but the basic 100% short term fix is to use text mode instead of graphical.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
...
Add this line:
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
...
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo reboot
```

Not as pretty, but at least there is some basic feedback that you entered a password and it's decrypting/wrong pass/etc

Comment: I installed Linux mint on a 7-9 year old motherboard that didn't even have UEFI and still had a blank screen. If I used the arrow keys it would show me a login prompt but otherwise it was just a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I couldn't even get into the "text based login" by pressing `Esc`, but like you, if I entered my password by just typing blindly, I could log in.

I fixed it by adding `nomodeset` to `/etc/default/grub` (after `splash`, so change `quiet splash` to `quiet splash nomodeset`), and then running `sudo update-grub`.

My PC has both "Intel Integrated graphics" and a graphics card, so I figured it had something to do with that. If your PC has this as well, you can try changing HDMI port, because I could see the prompt and what I entered when I changed ports.

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the same problem with my Linux Mint 17.3 installation right now. When the encryption screen should appear, for me it's possible to change the monitor source by pressing "Windows-Key + P" two times. Even if there is just one monitor connected to my computer, linux seems to think I want to use the HDMI instead of the DVI thats in fact connected.

I read some articles about the display settings that are not applied system-wide and that it should be possible to edit the default monitor in /etc/mdm/Init/Default. Unfortunately the solution didn't work for me either:

http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2015/08/configuring-the-mdm-login-screen-for-multiple-monitors/

Maybe it is helpful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem, but I just go back to a txt login screen by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, which then asks for the passphrase, then it unencrypts so I can get to the login screen. From there, no problems.